# Basic SQL count with LINQ

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq

I have a trivial issue that I can't resolve. Currently our app uses Linq to retrieve data and get a basic integer value of the row count. I can't form a query that gives back a count without a 'select i'. I don't need the select, just the count(*) response. How do I do this? Below is a sample:

```
return (from io in db._Owners
           where io.Id == Id && io.userId == userId
           join i in db._Instances on io.Id equals i.Id **select i**).Count()
```

;

Answer (score 3):

The `select i` is fine - it's not actually going to be fetching any data back to the client, because the `Count()` call will be translated into a `Count(something)` call at the SQL side.

When in doubt, look at the SQL that's being generated for your query, e.g. with the [`DataContext.Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) property.

Answer (score 1):

Using the LINQ query syntax requires a `select` statement. There's no way around that.

That being said, the statement will get transformed into a `COUNT()`-based query; the `select i` is there only to satisfy the expression system that underlies the LINQ query providers (otherwise the type of the expression would be unknown).

Answer (score 0):

Including the select will not affect the performance here because the final query will get translated into SQL.  At this point it will be optimized and will be like `select (*) from ......`